# Test Migration Azure Migration

Tags: azure, data-migration

I am using Azure migrate for my cloud virtual machine migration. I have replicated the machine in Azure and after that I click on Test migration. It started but synchronization taking too much time and status shows only 14% after 15 hours. Is it normal behavior or have i done something wrong?

Comment: How large is your virtual machine and what is the speed of your internet connection?

Comment: StackOverflow may not be the right forum to ask this question. Follow this thread to get the right forum https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117646/where-can-i-ask-questions-on-cloud-computing